¿Cuál es mi error en mi petición Post?
me podrían ayudar con mi problema, estoy intentando hacer una petición Post a una API.
Mi Código es el siguiente:
 private static void PostIm(string data)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.ejemplo.net/");
        var request = new RestRequest("getUrlImageWeb", Method.Post);
        
        MessageBox.Show("URL: " + client.BuildUri(request));
        // Crear el objeto JSON para el cuerpo de la solicitud
       
        string jsonText = @"{ ""products"": [""11PH407300311""] }";

        // Añadir el cuerpo de la solicitud como JSON
        request.AddJsonBody(jsonText);

        foreach (var param in request.Parameters)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(param.Name + param.Value);
        }

        // Ejecutar la solicitud y obtener la respuesta
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        // Imprimir el contenido de la respuesta
        MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
    }

En postman lo mando de la siguiente forma:
{"products":["11PH407300311"]}
y si me da respuesta.
El error que me regresa:
{ "httpCode":"401", "httpMessage":"Unauthorized", "moreInformation":"Invalid client id or secret." }
La api no solicita autorización

Que API estas tratando de consultar???

Desconozco un poco la librería que estas usando, podrias intentar en vez de mandarle una cadena, crear el objecto, de esta forma:
private static void PostIm(string data)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.ejemplo.net/");
        var request = new RestRequest("getUrlImageWeb", Method.Post);
        
        MessageBox.Show("URL: " + client.BuildUri(request));
        // Crear el objeto JSON para el cuerpo de la solicitud
       
        //string jsonText = @"{ ""products"": [""11PH407300311""] }"
        // Añadir el cuerpo de la solicitud como JSON
        //request.AddJsonBody(jsonText); <- Viejo 

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddJsonBody(new { products = ["11PH407300311"] }); // <- Nuevo

        foreach (var param in request.Parameters)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(param.Name + param.Value);
        }

        // Ejecutar la solicitud y obtener la respuesta
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        // Imprimir el contenido de la respuesta
        MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
    }

En caso de no funcionar, seria de checar con la version de RestSharp que estas usando, o probar con un endpoint mas simple y corroborar el funcionamiento adecuado del mismo.
De igual forma anexo la documentacion donde explican el funcionamiento de la libreria con JSON: https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#json-requests

El problema es debido a permisos para poder usar la API.
